# Visual Studio 2012 - How to automate open close curly brace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, macros, editor

In Visual Studio 2012 I created a macro to create an open curly brace, create a new line, create a new line, create closing brace and move cursor one line up followed by a TAB.

That macro was associated with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> so that after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> I was ready to write code.

How can I do the same in Visual Studio 2012 which doesn't have my macro?

Comment: program your own addin.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/80493a3w.aspx

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e2103b6-87cf-4fef-9410-a580c434b602

Comment: Thanks Fabian.
I ve created a plugin quick and dirty. Put this into Exec(...)

 TextSelection objSel = (EnvDTE.TextSelection)(_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection);

                        objSel.NewLine();
                        objSel.Insert("{"); objSel.Indent();
                        objSel.NewLine();
                        objSel.NewLine();
                        objSel.Insert("}"); objSel.Indent();
                        objSel.LineUp();
                        objSel.Indent();
                        objSel.SmartFormat();
                        objSel.LineUp();

Answer (score 1):

This is what I added to the wizard created prj: The install it in VS2012 and associate key combination: SHIFT+ALT+0

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
    {
        handled = false;
        if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
        {
            if(commandName == "CurlyBraces.Connect.CurlyBraces")
            {
                if (_applicationObject.ActiveDocument != null)
                {
                    TextSelection objSel = (EnvDTE.TextSelection)(_applicationObject.ActiveDocument.Selection);

                    objSel.NewLine();
                    objSel.Insert("{"); objSel.Indent();
                    objSel.NewLine();
                    objSel.NewLine();
                    objSel.Insert("}"); objSel.Indent();
                    objSel.LineUp();
                    objSel.Indent();
                    objSel.SmartFormat();
                    objSel.LineUp();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a free download from Visual Studio Gallery from the MSDN. 
I think you'll find this does the trick.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e2103b6-87cf-4fef-9410-a580c434b602